# iOS how to save map annotation and load them on a mapkit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, annotations

Do any of you know a way in Xcode where I can **save the coordinates** of an annotation every time a person puts an annotation pin on the map.

Then after I save this annotation, when a person clicks a button. The map shows all of the annotations ever saved and shows their location on the map.

I think  this is the most difficult problem in IOS because I don't see any tutorials or sample code. I don't think we know how to do this. Any geniuses??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The way to do is,store annotation coordinates somewhere in the app. 
You can store annotation coordinates in local xml/plist file or any another saving flat file saving mechanism and load them on fly. The other option is to use iOS CoreData (sqlite data store). Once you have them saved some where its all mater of reloading and using them..

I personally prefer coredata since it gives bit more flexibility than flat files..

Comment: I am using Parse and I managed to store coordinates to the cloud database, but I am having a hard time retrieving and using them. Any suggestions??

Comment: Not retrieving parse objects is an another issue.. it's hard to tell the problem without looking at the code.. but agin storing coordinates in cloud is also an option...

Comment: I wish I could put my code on here.  Specifically I am using Parse's find in background and I am trying to store coordinates in a nsarray. The hard part is pulling them out.